# Action filter that sets language globally in ASP.NET Core using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, custom-action-filter

I'm trying to create an `ActionFilter` that will read the `Accept-Language` header and find if it matches any value in `locale` and if it does not match, use the a default value which is `"en"`.

First of all, this is my handler:

```
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Subscription.Domain.Common;
using Subscription.Domain.Exceptions;
using Subscription.Infrastructure.Configuration;
using System.Net;

namespace Subscription.API.Application.Package.Queries.Get
{
    public class GetHandler : IRequestHandler<GetRequest, EntityResponseModel>
    {
        private readonly SubscriptionContext _context;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

        public GetHandler(SubscriptionContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
        {
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        public async Task<EntityResponseModel> Handle(GetRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var lang = _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();

            var packages = await _context.Packages.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                .Select(x => new GetResponseModel()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    BrandId = x.BrandId,
                    StartAt = x.StartAt,
                    IconUrl = x.IconUrl,
                    ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl,
                    CreatedAt = x.CreatedDate,
                    Title = x.PackageTranslations.FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.PackageId == x.Id && pt.Locale.Equals(lang)).Title,
                    Description = x.PackageTranslations.FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.PackageId == x.Id && pt.Locale.Equals(lang)).Description

                }).ToListAsync();

            if (!packages.Any())
            {
                throw new DomainException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No record found.");
            }

            return new EntityResponseModel()
            {
                Data = packages
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MediatR;
using Subscription.API.Application.Package.Queries.Get;
using Subscription.API.Application.Bundle.Queries.GetById;
using Subscription.API.Filters;

namespace Subscription.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PackagesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public PackagesController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ValidateHeaders]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var response = await _mediator.Send(new GetRequest() {  });

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

This the filter class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Subscription.API.Filters
{
    public class ValidateHeaders : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var headers = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
            // need to do something here
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically what I need is to create a filter that:

1. Check the `Accept-Language` header if it have a value that matches locale
2. If it does not have a value that matches it, return string with the default value which is `"en"`

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: You can modify the extension method in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210095/13092211) for your requirements. This answer is written for the built-in .Net Core Localization structure. I guess you are not using this localization structure. If you think this extension method in answer will be the solution, I can write an answer for your situation.

Comment: @bugrakosen Yes we are using PackageTranslation which contains all the languages for each package. my task is to create action filter to check if the language is available. if not, it returns a default value which is `en`. sorry if I didn't understand you well, I'm new to C# and .net and I'm lost.

Comment: @bugrakosen I need at least just an example on how to change the header value based on the filter.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want to do is to set a default value if there is no value in the request header. If that's the case I'll write an answer for it.

Comment: @bugrakosen Yes, exactly. but the process needs to be done in the action filter, not the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 different ways;

- Action Filter
- Middleware

### 1.Action Filter

If you use this action filter, you have to write this attribute on each endpoint.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Subscription.API.Filters
{
    public class ValidateHeaders : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var languageHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(languageHeader))
               context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage = "en";
        }
    }
}
```

### 2.Middleware

If you write it as middleware, it will be enough to place this middleware in the first place in the request pipeline.

```
public class ValidateHeadersMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ValidateHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var languageHeader = context.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(languageHeader))
            context.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage = "en";

        //Continue processing
        if (_next != null)
            await _next.Invoke(context);      
    }
}
```

This will effect all requests.

```
public static class MiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHeaderValidation(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ValidateHeadersMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

---

In the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` or minimal api configuration in `Program.cs`, use this middleware;

```
...
  
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHeaderValidation();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

...
```